# What is the problem with my attempt to create a matrix from individual files?

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a matrix from individual file lists. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nJvLwVDAdaMhRqTDMP6bP8sU8lgKLT1Y?usp=sharing

I get an error I can't resolve.  Is this indicating a problem with the matrix?

Here is my code:

```
#Create a matrix of African countries by themes in ICT news, 2015-2020

#Get the Bioconductor package
install.packages("BiocManager")
#Install the package to create the matrix
BiocManager:install("edgeR")
library("edgeR")

#Read in the files of themes from the African countries
myfilenames <- list.files(path="C:/Users/james/Desktop/Documents/Downloads/txtfiles",
                        pattern=".txt", full.names = TRUE)

#Create the matrix
y <- readDGE(files = myfilenames)                  

#Write the matrix to a file for later principal components analysis
 write.csv(y,"C:/Users/james/Desktop/Documents/Downloads/txtfiles/ICTThemesMatrix.csv")
```

Here is the error I get:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 38, 1442

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and update your question.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to write the output from a DGE matrix to a CSV file, one must extract the `counts` object from within the `DGEList` that is output by `readDGE()`.

To simulate the data I downloaded the Zimbabwe and Zambia data from the Google Drive location in the OP, converted the files to text, and processed as follows.

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
     install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("edgeR")
library(edgeR)
myfilenames <- list.files(path="./data/soEdgeR",
                          pattern=".txt", full.names = TRUE)
#Create the matrix
y <- readDGE(files = myfilenames)                  
countData <- as.data.frame(y$counts)
write.csv(countData,"./data/ICTThemesMatrix.csv",row.names = TRUE)
```

...and the first few rows of output from the resulting file.

```
"","./data/soEdgeR/ZambiaThemes","./data/soEdgeR/zimbabweThemes"
"WB_133_INFORMATION_AND_COMMUNICATION_TECHNOLOGIES",383332,466288
"WB_678_DIGITAL_GOVERNMENT",363450,436299
"WB_694_BROADCAST_AND_MEDIA",316324,395908
"MEDIA_MSM",207797,227087
"UNGP_FORESTS_RIVERS_OCEANS",199517,184102
"EPU_ECONOMY_HISTORIC",183074,191645
"CRISISLEX_CRISISLEXREC",171187,274515
"USPEC_POLICY1",166843,181172
"EDUCATION",162181,141294
```

Note that the first column in the CSV file contains the row names. One can convert the row names to an actual output column in the CSV (including a column name) as follows.

```
countData <- as.data.frame(y$counts)
countData$theme <- rownames(countData)
write.csv(countData,"./data/ICTThemesMatrix2.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
"./data/soEdgeR/ZambiaThemes","./data/soEdgeR/zimbabweThemes","theme"
383332,466288,"WB_133_INFORMATION_AND_COMMUNICATION_TECHNOLOGIES"
363450,436299,"WB_678_DIGITAL_GOVERNMENT"
316324,395908,"WB_694_BROADCAST_AND_MEDIA"
207797,227087,"MEDIA_MSM"
199517,184102,"UNGP_FORESTS_RIVERS_OCEANS"
183074,191645,"EPU_ECONOMY_HISTORIC"
171187,274515,"CRISISLEX_CRISISLEXREC"
166843,181172,"USPEC_POLICY1"
162181,141294,"EDUCATION"
```